# How to throw unwanted data from form?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, backend

I am making a site to add product to a database.

The site has a type switcher for multiple types of the product.
by changing the type the input fields are changed by using display attribute CSS.

so there is a problem where the invisible inputs are still in the form and they are also submitted with the form. Also I wanted to validate the data but it have the same problem how do I validate the data shown to the user?.
I tried to change the whole  by js document.create methods so I can create the inputs and labels I want but it was really complex . is there anyway I can fix this problem?

Here is the code I'm using:

```js
function TypeListener() {
  var x = document.getElementById("productType").value;
  document.getElementById("Hidden_Div1").style.display = x == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
  document.getElementById("Hidden_Div2").style.display = x == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
  document.getElementById("Hidden_Div3").style.display = x == 3 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
.Type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="product_form" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
  <label for="Type Switcher">Type Switcher</label>
  <select name="typeSwitcher" id="productType" onchange="TypeListener()">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Type Switcher</option>
    <option value="1" id="DVD">DVD</option>
    <option value="2" id="Furniture">Furniture</option>
    <option value="3" id="Book">Book</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <div id="Hidden_Div1" class="Type">
    <label for="Size">Size (MB)</label><input type="number" name="size" id="size" min="0"><br>
    <h5>Please, provide size in MB.</h5><br>
  </div>
  <div id="Hidden_Div2" class="Type">
    <label for="Height">Height (CM)</label><input type="number" name="height" id="height" min="0"><br>
    <label for="Width">Width (CM)</label><input type="number" name="width" id="width" min="0"><br>
    <label for="Length">Length (CM)</label><input type="number" name="length" id="length" min="0"><br>
    <h5>Please, provide dimensions in CM.</h5><br>
  </div>
  <div id="Hidden_Div3" class="Type">
    <label for="Weight">Weight (KG)</label><input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" min="0"><br>
    <h5>Please, provide weight in KG.</h5><br>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you wanna validate the data?

Comment: from the requirements of the page that i have to validate the data type and checking if its not empty and trigger notification to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

After making invisible entries that you want to be invisible, you can capture the visible entries with HTML Collection and send the data in it to the database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> **Tip:** In any current browser (as of Nov of 2015). Fields are submitted
> even if display is set to 'none'. Fields that are '`disabled`', however,
> will continue to not be submitted.

**Solution** *of submited data* **:**

```js
function TypeListener() {
    var x = document.getElementById("productType").value;
    if (x == 1){
        document.getElementById("Hidden_Div1").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementsByName("size")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Hidden_Div1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByName("size")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "");
    }
    if (x == 2){
        document.getElementById("Hidden_Div2").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementsByName("height")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
        document.getElementsByName("width")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
        document.getElementsByName("length")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Hidden_Div2").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByName("height")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "");
        document.getElementsByName("width")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "");
        document.getElementsByName("length")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "");
    }
    if (x == 3){
        document.getElementById("Hidden_Div3").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementsByName("weight")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Hidden_Div3").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByName("weight")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "");
    }
}
```

```css
.Type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="product_form" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
  <label for="Type Switcher">Type Switcher</label>
  <select name="typeSwitcher" id="productType" onchange="TypeListener()">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Type Switcher</option>
    <option value="1" id="DVD">DVD</option>
    <option value="2" id="Furniture">Furniture</option>
    <option value="3" id="Book">Book</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <div id="Hidden_Div1" class="Type">
    <label for="Size">Size (MB)</label><input type="number" name="size" id="size" min="0"><br>
    <h5>Please, provide size in MB.</h5><br>
  </div>
  <div id="Hidden_Div2" class="Type">
    <label for="Height">Height (CM)</label><input type="number" name="height" id="height" min="0"><br>
    <label for="Width">Width (CM)</label><input type="number" name="width" id="width" min="0"><br>
    <label for="Length">Length (CM)</label><input type="number" name="length" id="length" min="0"><br>
    <h5>Please, provide dimensions in CM.</h5><br>
  </div>
  <div id="Hidden_Div3" class="Type">
    <label for="Weight">Weight (KG)</label><input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" min="0"><br>
    <h5>Please, provide weight in KG.</h5><br>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply move / remove your form's parts in/out the form:

```js
const 
  formProd   = document.forms.product_form
, formParts  = document.querySelector('#form-parts') 
, d_switcher = document.querySelector('#div-switcher')
, formPart   = [...formParts.querySelectorAll('[id^="form-"]')].reduce((o,el)=>(o[el.id]=el,o),{})
  ;

var currentFormEl = null;

formProd.typeSwitcher.onchange =()=>
  {
  if ( currentFormEl )
    formParts.appendChild( currentFormEl ); // previous remove Out
    
  currentFormEl = formPart[`form-${formProd.typeSwitcher.value}`];
  
  d_switcher.appendChild( currentFormEl ); // move In
  }

formProd.onsubmit = e =>  // proof...
  {
  e.preventDefault()  // for testing....
  console.clear()
  console.log( Object.fromEntries( new FormData(formProd).entries() ) )
  }

formProd.onreset = () =>  // just in case...
  {
  if ( currentFormEl )
    formParts.appendChild( currentFormEl ); // previous remove Out
  }
```

```css
#form-parts { display: none; }

#div-switcher label {
  display : block;
  width   : 12em;
  height  : 2em ;
  margin  : .3em 0;
}
#div-switcher label input {
  width      : 5em;
  float      : right;
  transform  : translateY(-.3em);
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<form name="product_form" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
  <label>Type Switcher</label>
  <select name="typeSwitcher">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Type Switcher</option>
    <option value="DVD"       > DVD       </option>
    <option value="Furniture" > Furniture </option>
    <option value="Book"      > Book      </option>
  </select><br><br>

  <div id="div-switcher"></div>

  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  <button type="reset">reset</button>
  
</form>


<div id="form-parts">
  <div id="form-DVD">
    <label>Size (MB) <input type="number" name="size" id="size" min="0"></label>
    <h5>Please, provide size in MB.</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="form-Furniture">
    <label>Height (CM) <input type="number" name="height" min="0" value="0"></label>
    <label>Width (CM)  <input type="number" name="width"  min="0" value="0"></label>
    <label>Length (CM) <input type="number" name="length" min="0" value="0"></label>
    <h5>Please, provide dimensions in CM.</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="form-Book">
    <label>Weight (KG) <input type="number" name="weight" min="0" value="0"></label>
    <h5>Please, provide weight in KG.</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```